# Combine method calls for onLayout

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a component that uses the `onLayout` property. However I'd also like to receive the prop from the parent component and execute the given method, as well as the internal method.

In my component I have

```
onLayout = event => { 
  const { width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  this.setState({ width: width });
}
```

and in the render method I have

```
const { onLayout } = this.props;
return (
  <View onLayout={this.onLayout}>
  ...
  </View>
)
```

How can I combine `onLayout` the prop with the internal `this.onLayout`? I could create a new method but how do I deal with the `event` parameter, keeping the ES6 syntax?

Comment: I'd add the es2015 tag. As this seems really relevant to the question.

Comment: Also remove the three back ticks to format code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating new method combining two sub methods is good approach:

```
onLayout = event => {
  this.props.onLayout(event);
  this.updateWidth(event); 
}

updateWidth = event => {
  const { width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  this.setState({ width: width });
}
```

and in the render:

```
return (
  <View onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>
  ...
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind` method of Function prototype to bind your function to current context:

`<View onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>`

Comment: I don't understand how that would execute both methods?

Answer (score 1):

@Yuriy's answer was a good clue.

I passed `onLayout` as an argument via `bind`:

```
onLayoutInternal = (onLayout, event) => { 
  const { width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  this.setState({ width: width });
  onLayout(event);
}
```

Using bind like so:

```
render() {
  const { onLayout } = this.props;
  return (
    <View onLayout={this.onLayoutInternal.bind(this, onLayout)}>
  )
}
```